# boolean return issue/getting factors from method put into an array

Tags: java

after posting an hour ago about an earlier issue and getting a response within 4 min which was insane ill try my luck one more time. program has 5 methods, am currently making all of them so they will not all be on here(putting this in due to prior response) issue now is getting one of my last methods that actually does something other than making a print statement to work correctly. the method is not complete it needs to not only find the factors of said number but then also has to store them in an array, add them up and them determine if the number is perfect. the last method not shown is going to print out the actual array for each number if it has one. "testperfect" is the method i am having issues with, in eclipse i am getting an error saying  this method must return result in type boolean. . . any sort of help would be appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tgore_perfect 
{
 private static int count;
 private static int perfect;
 public static void main ( String args [])
 {
    count = getNum ();
    //System.out.print(count);
    boolean check = validateNum();
    //System.out.print(check);
    while (validateNum() == false)
    {
    System.out.print ("Non-positive numbers are not allowed.\n");
    count = getNum();
    }
    if (validateNum() == true)
    {
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        perfect = getPerfect();
        testPerfect();

    }
}
}



public static int getNum () //gets amount of numbers to process
 {
     Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
     int counter;

         System.out.println ("How many numbers would you like to test? ");
         counter = input.nextInt();
     return counter;
 }

 private static boolean validateNum() //checks user input
 { 
 if (count <= 0)
 {
     return false;
 }
 else
 {
     return true;
 }
 }

 public static int getPerfect() //gets number to process
 {
 Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in);
 perfect = -1;
 System.out.print ("Please enter a possible perfect number: ");
 return perfect = input.nextInt();
 }

 public static boolean testPerfect() //tests the number to see if is perfect
{
     int sum = 0;
     int x = 0;

     for( int i = 1; i < perfect; i++ )
 {
     if((perfect % i ) == 0 )
     {
         x = i;
         sum += x;

     }
     if( x == perfect)
     {
         return true;
     }
     else 
     {
         return false;
     }
}
}
}
```

Comment: All paths through your testPerfect() method must return a result. You should probably return a suitable value after your for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All code-paths must return your return-type**

Imagine if your for-loop **did not execute at all** because of your values of `i` and `perfect`, in that case, your function wouldn't return anything.

That **isn't permitted.**

```
public static boolean testPerfect() //tests the number to see if is perfect
{
    //...code...
    for( int i = 1; i < perfect; i++ )
    {
        //..code..
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: stupid mistake on my part, i guess i am unsure of how to ask the question i want to without just asking to have someone do the work for me which is unacceptable but with the way booleans work to put it bluntly i am unsure of how to get it to not only return the last true/false for the number being perfect along with outputting all the factors to an array... your post did answer my poorly thought out question though so should i check it as answered?

Comment: @user1826373 If it did solve the stated issue, you could mark it so. :)